# Install Plotly in Anaconda

Tags: python, plot, anaconda, conda

**How to install Plotly in Anaconda?**

The https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly says to `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly <package>`, and

The https://plot.ly/python/user-guide/ says to `pip install plotly`. I.e., without package.

So **which packages I should specify in Anaconda conda?**

I tried without one and get errors:

```
C:\>conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly
Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file
```

Comment: If you are using a conda environment, it is not recommended to use pip to install packages that are available through conda, because conda manages package dependencies in a way that pip does not. It can also FUBAR your environment. Review [Understanding Conda and Pip](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-conda-and-pip)

Comment: Also see [Getting Started with Plotly in Python: Installation](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#installation)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't care which version of Plotly you install, just use `pip`.

`pip install plotly` is an easy way to install the latest stable package for Plotly from PyPi.

`pip` is a useful package and dependency management tool, which makes these things easy, but it should be noted that Anaconda's `conda` tool will do the same thing.

`pip` will install to your Anaconda install location by default.

Check out [this](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html) description of package and environment management between `pip` and `conda`.

Edit: The link will show that `conda` can handle everything `pip` can and more, but if you're not trying to specify the version of the package you need to install, `pip` can be much more concise.

Comment: Why the bizarre focus on installing specific versions of packages? Both pip and conda give you the option to install a specific version.... _but if you're not trying to specify the version of the package you need to install, pip can be much more concise._ How come?

Answer (score 16):

### Clearing things up

- Conda is used to install **packages** (`plotly` is a package, `numpy` is a package, `cufflinks` is a package etc.)
- The list of available packages is found in some index, which in Conda parlance is called a **channel**. The default, "official" channel is maintained by Anaconda (Conda's developer), but anyone can open his own channel, and use it to distribute custom packages.

So, in the command you've shown:
`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly <package>`

- The `-c` switch tells Conda to use a custom channel which happens to be called `https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly`<sup>1</sup>
- `<package>` is the package to download from that channel.
- Specifying a channel is optional, and if you don't - then Conda will look in its default channels. But you **must specify a package so that Conda knows what to install.**

<sup>1 This is in fact a channel that belongs to a **user** called plotly, which is hosted on [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/about),  a free service offered by Anaconda to host custom channels.</sup>

### Back to your question

<s>This channel seems to be unmaintained (the `plotly` package hosted there is very old). Given that, and the fact that the [official plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/) says to use `pip`, that is what I would use.</s>

**Update:** plotly updated their conda build, and added conda as an installation option in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#installation) (albeit not in their [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/) website). So you can now safely use:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

or even simpler (since Anaconda Cloud channels are searched automatically):

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

When using Anaconda Python, conda is the preferred way to install packages, but in any case both conda and pip should be run under **Anaconda Prompt** on Windows (`Start --> Anaconda --> Anaconda Prompt`).
Installing packages from the standard command prompt when you have Anaconda is discouraged and can mess up your Anaconda installation.

Answer (score 6):

To install plotly in windows on anaconda.
Go to anaconda prompt, write in this code :

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

It will automatically update the modules and the rest should take care of itself. I also did not find the need to close and refresh spyder and the graphs started working on mine

Answer (score 4):

Using Anaconda, the following worked for me:

To search for which plotly packages are available on anaconda:
`anaconda search -t conda plotly`
This will provide a list of user/package for plotly available.

Decide which user/package works for your operating system and which version of Plotly you want. Then to get more information about that type in: `anaconda show [user]/[package]`. Installation instruction should be provided near the end. Typically, this is: `conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/[user] [package]` where you should replace [user] and [package] with the user/package of your preference.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have Anaconda installed than 'pip' might not work, in that case use:

**conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly**

Answer (score 2):

for:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import * 
import plotly.tools as tls
```

The next procedure worked for me in anaconda & jupyter

```
pip uninstall plotly

conda uninstall plotly

pip uninstall chart-studio

conda uninstall chart-studio

conda install -c plotly plotly chart-studio

pip install chart-studio

pip install plotly==3.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Anaconda prompt:

`pip install plotly`

It takes around a couple of minutes.