# How to install Plotly for Python 3 Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm a total beginner and I have a problem installing plotly to use it in my Jupyter Notebook. I have installed the Python 3 version. I am also using a Mac if that matters. 
I tried a variety of commands in the terminal but none of them worked.

This is my command in Jupyter Notebook:

```
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

print(__version__) # requires version >= 1.9.0
```

This is the error I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.
Desperate beginner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072117/install-plotly-in-anaconda This might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Freedom Frog. I have seen this question but none of these answers could help me. I have tried to run all the commands in my terminal but none of them worked. Could there maybe be a more basic problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have now solved the problem. I just opened a new Terminal and made sure that I wrote the command

```
pip install cufflinks
```

directly after the second line.

The same worked for

```
pip install plotly
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, I downloaded the file to local drive, and pip installed from there

Answer (score 2):

Download whl file:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/77/905effe9361395d3e094ffd2b54b4085d339a7b7de9c2c91fa55ec257422/plotly-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

use `pip install C:\Users\Downloads\plotly-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 0):

Official [documentation page](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/) says:

For use in the classic Jupyter Notebook, install the `notebook` and `ipywidgets` packages using pip...

```
$ pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"
```

or conda.

```
$ conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"
```

These packages contain everything you need to run a Jupyter notebook...

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

Display plotly figures inline using the notebook renderer...

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```