# i am receiving an error when trying to install plotly in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, plotly

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

pip install plotly

restarted the kernel,also tried to install as conda.not working!!!

Comment: https://anaconda.org/plotly/plotly do not use pip to install packages that are available through conda when using a conda environment. Also see https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/#installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Plotly in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072117/install-plotly-in-anaconda)